# is there a way to exclude certain chars from encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript

i am building a query string for my url and need to exclude certain chars from the encode.

I want to exclude the "&" and the "=" so that I can make a statement as such:

first=blah&second=blah and so on....

I guess the best way to put it is how do I stop them from being encoded?

some code:

```
 else if (array[i].nodeName == "SELECT") {
   if (array[i].id == "multiple") {
     var selected = $.map($('#multiple option:selected'),

     function (e) {
       return $(e).val();
     });
     $.each(selected, function (index, value) {
       name = array[i].name;
       values += app + "\&" + key + "=";
     });

   } else {
     name = arr[i].name;
     values = arr[i].value;
   }
 }

 key = encodeURIComponent(name);
 value = encodeURIComponent(values);
 queryString += name + "=" + values + "&";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to exclude certain chars from `encodeURIComponent`?

No.  It's a builtin function that takes exactly one argument.

---

You do need to encode `&` when it appears in the middle of a key or value so the simplest solution is to encode the individual names and values before combining them.  Define

```
function emit(name, value) {
  queryString += (queryString.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?")
    + encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
```

and then call that function for each name/value pair in multiple selects or once for each other checked input.

```
else if (array[i].nodeName=="SELECT" ){
  if(array[i].id == "multiple"){
    var selected = $.map( $('#multiple option:selected'),
                          function(e){return $(e).val();});
    $.each(selected, function(index, value){
             emit(array[i].name, value);
           });
  } else {
    emit(arr[i].name, arr[i].value);
  }
}
```

Using `encodeURI` or similar will not properly encode `#`, `=` or other necessary code-points.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function should suggest how it should be used: call it on the **pieces** of the query string, not the whole query string.

*edit* — I've tried to create an example based on your code, but I can't figure out what it's trying to do. As it stands it seems to have syntax errors.